# Pseudo-element image not displaying on GitHub Pages

Tags: css, image, github, frontend, pseudo-element

I'm pretty new to programming and using Github and can't figure this one out so help would be appreciated.

I'm doing a little challenge and have got everything looking good on Chrome and other browsers; however, when I try to post to GitHub Pages, one set of images (which are pseudo-elements) are missing. The way the folder is organized is that I have one main folder, two sub-folders (a CSS folder and an image folder), and then the HTML. My folder with everything is here: https://github.com/aelizabethian/Accordion-Card_HTML_CSS_Javascript

In my CSS, for the arrows, I have;

```
question::after {
  content: url("/images/icon-arrow-down.svg");
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  right: 0px;
}
```

I've read that the / is not so great because Github gets confused and omits it, but the problem is that if I omit this, the arrows disappear in Chrome. I've also tried "../" and "./" but nothing works. I'm sure this is an easy fix but I'm stumped. Help is appreciated. My other images aren't having this problem so I'm wondering if it has something to do with being a pseudo-element.

Comment: Write full url instead of relative. Also try to inspect webpage from where this image is loaded

Comment: Thanks Justinas - because my images otherwise were fine, I finally figured out that the issue was that I put the image as content: url() and while that worked fine in Chrome, it caused an issue in GitHub Pages finding the image. When I re-jiggered it to background-image: url() instead it worked. Go figure..